# Angular 5 - Redirect to root of application on browser refresh

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 application.
Say a route is loaded for e.g.
http://localhost:3000/ui/customers/9/billing

if i refresh the page in the browser, it automatically goes to the 
http://localhost:3000/ui/customers/9/billing component; is there any way to make it load the http://localhost:3000/ui/customers route (component)?

I have tried using HashLocationStrategy but it is not working.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234250/angular-5-redirect-page-to-homepage-on-browser-refresh) is the same, but i did not understand the solution provided.

Comment: Why would it be a good idea, if a user decides to refresh the current page, to go to a different page than the one he/she explicitly asked to refresh?

Comment: If he refreshes the page, i want him to start over by visiting the parent route /customers. Or to the root of the application

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My point is that it's a bad idea. If I ask to refresh the current page, it's because I want to refresh the current page. Not because I want to go elsewhere. If someone goes to a bar and asks for a beer, and gets a coke instead, that's not right.

Comment: Besides the fact, that i also think this it not a good idea in general - the solution would be to redirect to your "root" page within the constructor of you app.component.ts

Comment: @AJT_82 provide the best solution on your shared question link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234250/angular-5-redirect-page-to-homepage-on-browser-refresh

Comment: Got it thanks. it works now.

Comment: actually the router loses any sense here. The whole point of router is having persistent URLs that are keeping the connection to the view. By resetting it on any URL call you just, well, destroy the whole idea